# Distribute events over the network

Tags: cqrs, event-sourcing, axon, axon-framework

I'm trying to use Axon framework for an event sourcing-based application and I need to publish certain types of events so other services can be aware of that for specific purposes (statistics, email servicing, etc.). The problem is that, from Axon's documentation, services should share the event store to subscribe to these events (see [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-framework/events/event-bus-and-event-store#distributing-events)). This is a violation of the microservice architecture because services are sharing the DB, although the schema will not change over time, because it's an event store. Another option is to set up Kafka or another message broker like RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ or any other AMQP compatible broker. However, that means that those message brokers would also be responsible for persisting in the event, which is not ideal. My question is: is there any way to persist the events in a non-shared datastore but also publish the events to another service in a topic or a queue?

Thanks.

Comment: After coming back to this issue because of the interaction on my answer, I had another look at your question. I completely agree the referred section provides incorrect information that conflicts with current standards for application development. As such, I've added an issue to the Reference Guide to update this section accordingly. 

As far as this does justice, apologies for this, Tomas. I'll reply back as soon as the update's been committed. If you're interested, you can find the issue here - https://github.com/AxonIQ/reference-guide/issues/225

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for taking care of this. There's no need for apologies, it's a technical discussion and it's pretty useful. Hope we can help to improve Axon. Is it possible to check the source code of the event store or is it private?

Comment: The standard edition of Axon Server is open core and can be viewed here (https://github.com/AxonIQ/axon-server-se). The enterprise edition, which incorporates RAFT for distributed consensus, is closed. This means that the RAFT specifics are not visible. The storage solution is part of Axon Server Standard though, so you can definitely take a look there. I believe you've already found the repository though, which I base on this issue you've constructed - https://github.com/AxonIQ/axon-server-se/issues/390

Comment: Just wanted to update everyone that the "Distributing Events" section mentioned in this question has been updated. As such, the described predicament should be resolved, albeit conceptually correct, still.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that sharing the database between services would violate the principles of SOA and thus the principles of Microservices.  Surprising that they suggest this in their documentation.

Here is an approach I have taken, making some assumptions about your setup:  expose the events in the Event Store to outside consumers via an http endpoint (API). The API will likely allow filtering of events from a certain checkpoint/date, and also by stream/aggregate Id.  Then use a message broker or ESB to broadcast notification events, which are distinct from event store events and only contain enough information to alert downstream services that something changed so that they can then query the API.  The sequence would be something like:

1. Change is made to WidgetA
2. Main Service broadcasts a message that WidgetA changed on XX date
3. Consuming Service receives WidgetChangedEvent
4. Consuming Service queries Main Service's API for events with WidgetA's Id that are later than XX date

Comment: I'm thinking about getting rid of Axon and start using DynamoDB as an event store since it does let me save and broadcast the event atomically to other services (and to the same process too, of course). The challenge would be to replay all the events from the datastore and manage the snapshots, but anyways...

Comment: If you're considering getting rid of Axon, I'd suggest looking at the combination of Akka Persistence (to handle writing events to a DB in a schema optimized for replay, as well as managing the snapshots) and Akka Persistence Query to publish events as they come in to message queues for inter-service/inter-context communication.

Answer (score 0):

What's key to take into account, is that in a microservices landscape, some services **do** belong to the same context, and others do not.
The ones that do, would conceptually be part of the same (bounded) context.
The services within a context furthermore could just as well be regarded as a single service. From that perspective, sharing the data source/schema should not be problematic.

It's as soon as the scope broadens and you have distinct contexts, which I assume you have in your setup, Tomás, then you would introduce some kind of broadcast mechanism for your events.

The ideal choice for a system that would use Event Sourcing honestly is an actual Event Store. Hence, [Axon Server](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/axon-server/introduction) (or [EventStore.com](https://www.eventstore.com/)) would be your only reasonable option, as those are Event Store database types. Axon Server also provides the means to define the contexts I've just mentioned, to automatically construct distinct storage locations and message streams to keep the data separated.

The referred-to piece of documentation has some unlucky wording when it comes to Axon Server, I must admit that. I'd wager some adjustment is in place for the documentation to mitigate this confusion.

When it comes to the `EmbeddedEventStore`, which I assume you're using, I'd like to clear up the following. You should take that although the data source is shared, nothing states that this data source should contain your application-specific schemas. It's actually recommended to use a distinct data source just of your events. This would, as you already mention, not form a problem as there is no concern of schema mixture when doing so. You would set this up. per (earlier mentioned) context. since you definitely don't want your events between distinct contexts to be combined. It is with this setup, and the requirement to distribute events to other contexts, that the alternatives (in the perspective of a dedicated Message Router like Axon Server) AMQP or Kafka can be used.

I still agree it's not the ideal solution; that would be a dedicated Event Store implementation like Axon Server. So, let me refer to the question you've posed in your message:

> is there any way to persist the events in a non-shared datastore but also publish the events to another service in a topic or a queue?

Yes, there is. Ideally, you'd use a dedicated Event Store like Axon Server. Or a diligently controlled combination of context-separated single-purpose data sources and brokers.

As you are already using Axon Framework, trying out Axon Server should be a piece of cake though, so I'd take that route.

Comment: If you are recommending a product in your answer, and *especially* if you are claiming it's only one of two reasonable options, you should absolutely disclose any relationship you have to that product.  Your profile states that you are the Lead Developer for the Axon Framework.

Comment: I figured that could be made clear by checking my profile, as you've spotted too. Added, note that Axon Server is free to use. From that perspective, I'd regard both Axon Framework and Axon Server products. On any note, my apologies if I've missed a code-of-conduct on the matter; just wanted to share the intended views from the perspective of Axon Framework. Hope that's still clear from my reply. If not, let me know what you'd expect otherwise and I'll update my response.

Comment: Hi Steven. Bounded contexts are not meant to use the same database if they are different microservices. We may have 20 microservices for a single bounded context or subdomain. Databases should not be shared even if the same team handles the bounded context's microservices. Even though I don't save specific schemas in the event store, that's a critical point in the system and should not be shared. Other mechanisms should be provided, something like dynamo streams or even mongo subscription to changes

Comment: I agree, _between_ bounded contexts you wouldn't share the source. But _within_ a bounded context, I wouldn't foresee an immediate issue with sharing, honestly. That's at least the point I tried to put across in my answer. If there's a part that's unclear on that fact, let me know (so that I can adjust the wording).

Note that although the argument on databases still stands, the conceptual role of the Event Store is entirely different in this. To correctly support Event Sourcing, it's paramount such a source is used, and ideally a dedicated Event Store implementation at that.